# NodeJs App Crashes in module.js Before Executing Procfile Module on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've run my NodeJs app locally on my Windows 7 computer without any problem running on `0.8.18`.  However, when I push it to Heroku and try to visit the URL, the following error is logged:

```
2013-04-27T19:34:14.073833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-27T19:34:59.340168+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=myapp.org fwd="108.212.64.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-27T19:35:00.565119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myapp.org fwd="108.212.64.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-27T19:44:23.916316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node myApp.js`
2013-04-27T19:44:24.424716+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-27T19:44:24.425324+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/myApp.js:7
2013-04-27T19:44:24.425680+00:00 app[web.1]:    ;
2013-04-27T19:44:24.425725+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^
2013-04-27T19:44:24.429639+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
2013-04-27T19:44:24.429639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
2013-04-27T19:44:24.429639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
2013-04-27T19:44:24.429639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2013-04-27T19:44:24.429639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2013-04-27T19:44:24.429639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
2013-04-27T19:44:24.429639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9)
2013-04-27T19:44:25.437926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-27T19:44:25.414435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-27T19:44:22.954367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

My procfile simply reads:

```
web: node myApp.js
```

My `package.json` reads:

```
{
  "name": "Arbol",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0",
"bcrypt": "0.7.5",
"connect-flash": "0.1.0",
"sequelize":"1.4.1",
"ejs":"0.8.3",
"oath":"0.2.3",
"node-markdown":"0.1.1",
"pg":"0.15.1",
"passport":"0.1.16",
"passport-twitter":"0.1.4",
"passport-google":"0.3.0",
"passport-facebook":"0.1.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

Additionally, here are the first lines of `myApp.js`:

```
console.log('neither here');
var express = require('express'),
app = module.exports = express(),
passport = require('passport'),
flash = require('connect-flash'),
FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy,
TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy,
GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
console.log('nor there');
```

Neither of the `console.log` messages are logged when deployed to Heroku.

It seems that nothing in `myApp.js` is causing this issue, but rather it is being caused by `Module`.  What is `Module.js`?  Where can I find it and why would my app cause a problem in it?

Comment: Not sure if it's case sensitive, but your procfile reads myapp.js while your file name is myApp.js (capital A).

Comment: that was my careless mistake - I replaced the name of my real Procfile module with `myApp.js` just for this post.

Comment: Can you post your package.json? What node version are you using locally and on heroku?

Comment: I'm running on 0.8.19 locally.  How can I see what version I'm running on Heroku?

Comment: excellent, I explicitly stated nodejs version `0.8.19` instead of `0.8.x` and it worked.  I suppose I don't understand anything any better, but it did work.  Thanks for the comment.  Do you recommend I upgrade my node version locally and on Heroku?

Comment: Well, I guess newer is better... I recently upgrade to 0.10.5 and it went pretty smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed by package.json to explicitly state the exact node version and the problem went away:

```
  "engines": {
     "node": "0.8.19",
   "npm": "1.1.x"
   }
```